# Is it possible in Cassandra (CQL3) insert statement binary data?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cql3

My goal is populate cassandra with some data using a script.
I'm looking for something like:

```
CREATE TABLE simplex.songs (id uuid PRIMARY KEY, img blob);
INSERT INTO simplex.songs (id, img) VALUES(2cc9ccb7-6221-4ccb-8387-f22b6a1b354d, hexAsBlob({hex representation of my image}));
```

or

```
INSERT INTO simplex.songs (id, img) VALUES(2cc9ccb7-6221-4ccb-8387-f22b6a1b354d, readFromFile({ image file name}));
```

Is it possible? I know **hexAsBlob & readFromFile** do not exist, but maybe there is something similar?
And because it's script I cannot use BoundStatement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an hexadecimal literal in CQL.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO simplex.songs (id, img) 
VALUES (2cc9ccb7-6221-4ccb-8387-f22b6a1b354d, 0xaa001112);
```

From [CQL3 documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#constants): A blob constant is an hexadecimal number defined by 0xX+ where hex is an hexadecimal character, e.g. [0-9a-fA-F].